# image, js and css resources aren't working on jsp pages

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jsp, cloudbees

Techies--
This is a simple servlet/jsp/tomcat application. I want to add a style sheet, images and a few java script files. I'm using eclipse (kepler). The deployment is to a PaaS, Cloudbees server.

I've added the js library to the project -- which shows up in the eclipse project as a resource library under the JavaScript Resources. The actual files show up in the js directory in the project.

I've added the style sheet under src\main\webapp\WEB-INF  as style.css

Here's what the links look like in my jsp page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="WEB-INF/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/georgia.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cuf_run.js"></script>  
<title>Water Conservation and Reservoir Data Depot</title>
</head>
```

The images are under the project under a directory called images

images are referenced as follows in my jsp pages:

```
  <img src="images/img_1.gif" alt="" width="89" height="78" class="floated" />
```

I thought I set up the js and css files correctly. I'm not sure about the image files, but since none of them are showing, apparently I didn't get any of it right! :(

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using `WEB-INF`; the HTML page is sent to the client, not automagically rewritten on the server. You should also probably be using absolute paths instead of relative. Figure out how to load the resources manually in the browser, then make the delivered HTML match those URLs.

Comment: @chrylis, since I'm deploying to a PaaS I'm a little confused about what the relative paths/absolute paths might actually be. For the images is there a way to package them up and reference them within the html/anchor tags? I'll settle for ANY successes this evening! :)

Comment: You're saying `js/` and `images/`, which is relative to the page location. Use `/js/` to make sure that you're not getting confused if your page is in a directory.

Comment: *sigh* . It was a valiant try. then i tried ../js/ and ../images -- same results: http://sfinterfacetomcat8.metro-pojo.cloudbees.net/greenpeace_index.jsp

Comment: Just figure out how to load the images directly in your browser first. Generally speaking, it's going to be a lot easier to run this locally first rather than going through CloudBees (especially since CloudBees is shutting down their PaaS).

Comment: The plain html, css, js works fine in the browsers with the links as posted--but you're thinking looking @this through a browser via a local server set up on my laptop, right?

Answer (score 0):

1. don't use relative URL ("images/img_1.gif") but absolute ones ("/images/img_1.gif")
2. don't place static resources under WEB-INF. This folder is by nature never directly exposed to web requests, only accessible through a servlet mapping definition.

Comment: If only I could get an absolute to work (or a relative to work)! :-\  I did force the the css to load at least with this line: <style>
        <%@include file="WEB-INF/style.css" %>
</style> . I am about to do something similar for the *.js scripts. The Cloudbees deployment is on a Tomcat 8 server--no adapter for Kepler-- so I'm blind to where these files are actually getting loaded to figure out what is relative. Frustrating for what should have been a 10 minute effort.

Comment: BTW, I'll move the style sheets out of  WEB-INF to /resources/images. Where in the tree is best?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

I moved the images directory, the style.css and js directory under the webapp directory via the opssys; used include file for jscript and css; getcontext for image references.